# Live wallpaper not shown in tablet's google play

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I published a live wallpaper, but which can only be found on phones' Google Play. If I search it on my tablet's Google play, the item is not found. I tried to install the wallpaper on my tablet manually, it runs without problems. Will google somehow determine my live wallpaper is not suitable for tablets and hid my app? Thank you!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tdf.freshpaper"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="0.9">    
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service
        android:name="com.tdf.fresh.MainActivity"
        android:description="@string/wallpaper_description"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.tdf.fresh.SettingsActivity"
        android:exported="true"``
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Log in to you [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/#), there should be a section call `Optimization Tips`. If for some reason you app is not compatible with tablets, you will find there the reason why.

Anyways you can try this in your manifest:

```
 <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But what if I just want my lwp searchable on tablets Google play, but not installable on tablet. Because my lwp is not quite tablet friendly.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.